# BentoML: how to build a model without importing the services.py file?

Tags: machine-learning, bentoml

Is it possible to run `bentoml build` without importing the `services.py` file during the process?

I'm trying to put the bento build and containarize steps in our CI/CD server. Our model depends on some OS packages installed and some python packages. I thought I could run `bentoml build` to package the model code and binaries that are present.  I'd leave the dependencies especification to the contanairize step.

To my surprise the bentoml build process tried to import the service file during the packaging and the build failed since I didn't have the dependencies installed in my CI/CD machine.

Can I prevent this importing while building/packaging the model? Maybe I should ignore the bento containarize and create my bento container by hand and just execute the bentoml serve inside.

I feel that the need to install by hand the dependencies is doubling the effort to specify them in the bentofile.yaml and preventing the reproducibility of my environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible. The community is working on an environment management feature, such that an environment with the necessary dependencies will be automatically created during build.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This may not solve the problem, since and non admin user won't be able to install OS dependencies. The build must be made inside the container.